# Construction of a PDA for the binary and decimal representation of a number

Tags: automata-theory

I have the solution with me for this question but I have really hard time understanding the construction. Can anyone may be break it down in a simpler way?

**Problem:**
Given $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$. Consider the language $L := \{ wa^{w_2} | w \in \{0, 1\}^n\}$. Construct a deterministic PDA for $L$ using $O(n)$ stack symbols and states. Additionally, the stack height should be bounded by $O(n)$.
An example would be $1100a^{12} \in L$

**Solution Sketch:**
Let $(Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, q_n, Z_0, \delta)$ be the PDA, where:

- $Q := \{q_0, \dots , q_n\}$
- $\Sigma := \{0, 1, a\}$
- $\Gamma := \{Z_0, A_1, \dots , A_n\}$

Define the transition function $\delta$ as follows:

- $\delta(q_i, 0, X) := \{(q_{i−1}, X)\}$, for $i \in \{1, \dots , n\}, X \in \Gamma$
- $\delta(qi, 1, X) := \{(q_{i−1}, A_i X)\}$, for $i \in \{1, \dots , n\}, X \in \Gamma$
- $\delta(q_0, \epsilon, A_i) := \{(q_0, A_{i−1}A_{i−1})\}$, for $i ∈ {2, . . . , n}$
- $\delta(q_0, a, A_1) := {(q_0, \epsilon)}$
- $δ(q_0, \epsilon, Z_0) := {(q_0, \epsilon)}$

**Idea:**
For each power of two $2^i$, introduce a stack symbol. If we encounter the stack symbol for $2^0 = 1$, we read an "a". Otherwise, we break down the stack symbol for $2^{i+1}$ into two stack symbols for $2^i$.

Comment: What does a^(w)2 mean?

Comment: @MartinBerger like for example 1100a^12 1100 is the binary representation followed by a and then power of the number

Comment: In your example, is $a$ repeated 12 times, i.e. the word is $1100aaaaaaaaaaaa$ ?